# Can anyone explain how can I print the order of the matrix after matrix chain multiplication?

Tags: matrix, multiplication, chain

I have to find the order of matrix formed after matrix chain multiplication. 
I have the following code to determine the minimum number of multiplications required to multiply all matrices:

```html
ll MatrixChainOrder(ll p[], ll n) {
 ll m[n][n], i, j, k, L, q;
 for(i = 1; i < n; i++) {
  m[i][i] = 0;
 }
 for(L = 2; L < n; L++) {
  for(i = 1; i < n - L + 1; i++) {
   j = i + L - 1;
   m[i][j] = INT_MAX;
   for(k = i; k <= j - 1; k++) {
    q = m[i][k] + m[k+1][j] + p[i-1] * p[k] * p[j];
    if (q < m[i][j]) {
     m[i][j] = q;
    }
   }
  }
 }
 return m[1][n-1];
}
```

How can I print the order of the matrix as well? Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use another auxiliary matrix (`s` for example), with indices.

```
if (q < m[i][j]) {
    m[i][j] = q;
    s[i][j] = k;
}
```

With matrices `m` and `s` you can print recursively the best matrix parenthesization.

[image: PRINT-OPTIMAL-PARENS]

Comment: In cormen Books, "Introduction to Algorithms" theres a example in page 336.